# Sample code from scikit-learn.org is giving error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

when I try to learn One HotEncoder from sklearn library, I tried the [following sample code](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) given provided by scikit-learn.org. But this code gives me error and I am not able to debug it.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]
enc.fit(X)
```

I get this error:

```
array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Male'
```

I am assuming if this code is written on scikit-learn.org, then the problem must be in my environment or is it something I am doing wrong here.

Comment: It works for me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is arguably related to your scikit-learn version. From version 0.20, `OneHotEncoder` can handle strings, which was not the case in older versions - notice that the documentation for v0.19 doesn't provide the same example:
https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

The [release notes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#id20) for the version Version 0.20.2 (December 18) mention this specifically:

> **Major Feature**: Expanded `preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` to allow to encode categorical string features as a numeric array using a one-hot (or dummy) encoding scheme

So, upgrade your scikit-learn to the current version (0.20), and you should be fine.

Comment: *Now* it is an answer (previously was a comment)... downvote & flag retracted

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the edit on my answer, desertnaut!